# How to change the field type in an ElasticSearch Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have index_A, which includes a number field "foo".

I copy the mapping for index_A, and make a dev tools call `PUT /index_B` with the field foo changed to text, so the mapping portion of that is:

"foo": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword"
}
}

I then reindex index_A to index_B with:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_A"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_B"
  }
}
```

When I go to view any document for index_B, the entry for the "foo" field **is still a number**. (I was expecting for example: "foo": 30 to become "foo" : "30" in the new document's source).

As much as I've read on Mappings and reindexing, I'm still at a loss on how to accomplish this. What specifically do I need to run in order to get this new index with "foo" as a text field, and all number entries for foo in the original index changed to text entries in the new index?

Answer (score 1):

There's a distinction between how a field is *stored* vs *indexed* in ES. What you see inside of `_source` is stored and it's the "original" document that you've ingested. But there's no explicit casting based on the mapping type -- ES **stores** what it receives but then proceeds to **index** it as defined in the mapping.

In order to verify how a field was **indexed**, you can inspect the script stack returned in:

```
GET index_b/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "debugging_foo": {
      "script": {
        "source": "Debug.explain(doc['foo'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as opposed to how a field was **stored**:

```
GET index_b/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "debugging_foo": {
      "script": {
        "source": "Debug.explain(params._source['foo'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in other words, rest assured that **`foo` was indeed indexed as `text` + `keyword`**.

If you'd like to explicitly cast a field value into a different data type **in the `_source`**, you can apply a script along the lines of:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_a"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_b"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.foo = '' + ctx._source.foo"
  }
}
```

*I'm not overly familiar with java but I think `... = ctx._source.foo.toString()` would work too.*

---

FYI there's a [`coerce` mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) which sounds like it *could* be of use here but it only works the other way around -- casting/parsing from strings to numerical types etc.

---

FYI#2 There's a pipeline processor called [`convert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html) that does exactly what I did in the above script, and more. (A pipeline is a pre-processor that runs *before* the fields are indexed in ES.) The good thing about pipelines is that they can be run as part of the `_reindex` process too.